# Android: building a string reference

Tags: java, android, string

I have three strings in strings.xml:

```
<string name="book_1">Tom Sawyer</string>
<string name="book_2">Huck Finn</string>
<string name="book_3">Roughing It</string>
```

I understand that I can reference a string from java by explicitly choosing a string:

```
String book = R.string.book_1;
```

If I have int x which stores book number, how do I reference string book_x?

UPDATE AND SOLUTION:
I figured out what I was looking for.  This was my first Stackoverflow question and I should have given more context. I promise I will get better at this. Thanks to all who responded.

```
// Getting book title.  Displaying the book title in the TextView
// int booknumber is already defined
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.booktitle_textview);
String bookName = "book_" + Integer.toString(booknumber);
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(bookName, "string", "com.example.mypackage");
tv.setText(getString(resourceId));
```

Comment: I am looking for a way not to hard code but build an expression.

Answer (score 3):

Put the three strings in an array:

```
String[] strs = {R.string.book_1, R.string.book_2, R.string.book_3};
```

Then access the appropriate element using `strs[x - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Switch` or `If`. But the cleaner approach is the one @AndyTurner said.

Switch

```
private String getBookBySwitch(int number) {
    String result = "";

    switch (number) {
    case 0:
        result = R.string.book_1;
        break;
    case 1:
        result = R.string.book_2;
        break;
    case 2:
        result = R.string.book_3;
        break;
    default:
        result = "NONE";
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If statement

```
private String getBookByIf(int x) {
    String result = "";

    if (number == 0)
        result = R.string.book_1;
    else if (number == 1)
        result = R.string.book_2;
    else if (number == 2)
        result = R.string.book_3;

    return result; 
}
```

Both are valid but the cleanest one is this:

```
private String getBookByArray(int x) {
    String result = "";

    String[] arrayOfBookStrings = {R.string.book_1, R.string.book_2, R.string.book_3};

    result = arrayOfBookStrings[x];

    return result;
}
```

Remember that `x` needs to start from 0 and not from 1. If you do start from 1 then you need to subtract 1 from `x` as follows: `x - 1`.